# Как изменить словарь, который возвращает serializer.data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dict

Есть словарь

> {
> "id": 1,
> "title": "gallery 1",
> "cover": {
> "photo": "gallery/1/sjz-COq95j0.jpg"
> }
> }

Как мне сделать так, чтобы слово photo не было, как убрать эту лишнюю вложенность? Чтобы к примеру было так:

> {
> "id": 1,
> "title": "gallery 1",
> "cover": "gallery/1/sjz-COq95j0.jpg"
> }

Вот код сериализатора:

```
class GalleryImagesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    photo = serializers.ImageField(use_url=False)


class GalleryListSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cover = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_cover(self, obj):
        return GalleryImagesSerializer(obj.photos.first()).data

    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'cover')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измени метод `get_cover`, что бы он не возвращал словарь, а только нужный ключ из этого словаря

```
    def get_cover(self, obj):
        return GalleryImagesSerializer(obj.photos.first()).data.get('photo')
```

Comment: Спасибо, смог сам пораньше разобраться, сделал просто data['photo']

Answer (score 0):

Я понял как это надо было сделать. Просто из serializer.data сделать serializer.data['photo']